# PHP JSON Array to Javascript decoding

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following json which is returned by Influxdb which I can decode with PHP with out any issue i.e I use the following code:

```
$json_result = json_decode($json_result, true);
$http_result_series_0 = $json_result["results"][0]["series"][0] ["values"][0][5];
```

Now I would like to do the decoding with javascript in order to dynamically fill a table. But no matter how I try to do it, it's not working. I know that there's a similar way in javascript to decode the Array i.e:

```
json_result.results[0].series[0].values[0][5]
```

The json:

```
"{
    "results": [
        {
            "statement_id": 0,
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "default_lte_stick_1_test.com_http_response",
                    "tags": {
                        "server": "https://twitter.com"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "host",
                        "http_response_code",
                        "method",
                        "response_time",
                        "result",
                        "result_code",
                        "result_type",
                        "status_code",
                        "tag1",
                        "tag2"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "2018-10-12T11:19:12Z",
                            "xps",
                            200,
                            "GET",
                            1.358607871,
                            "success",
                            0,
                            "success",
                            "200",
                            "test.com",
                            "LTE"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "default_lte_stick_1_test.com_http_response",
                    "tags": {
                        "server": "https://google.com"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "host",
                        "http_response_code",
                        "method",
                        "response_time",
                        "result",
                        "result_code",
                        "result_type",
                        "status_code",
                        "tag1",
                        "tag2"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "2018-10-12T11:19:10Z",
                            "xps",
                            301,
                            "GET",
                            0.051518655,
                            "success",
                            0,
                            "success",
                            "301",
                            "test.com",
                            "LTE"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "default_lte_stick_1_test.com_http_response",
                    "tags": {
                        "server": "https://amazon.com"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "host",
                        "http_response_code",
                        "method",
                        "response_time",
                        "result",
                        "result_code",
                        "result_type",
                        "status_code",
                        "tag1",
                        "tag2"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "2018-10-12T11:19:11Z",
                            "xps",
                            301,
                            "GET",
                            0.536477796,
                            "success",
                            0,
                            "success",
                            "301",
                            "test.com",
                            "LTE"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"
```

What I'm doing wrong? Every help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

The Influxdb API returns a pretty formated JSON. Currently I output the whole JSON with:

```
var json_result = '<?php echo $javascript_json_result;?>'; 
document.getElementById("jsonoutput").innerHTML = JSON.parse(json_result);
```

which outputs the whole json. But I would like to output only single values.

```
document.getElementById("jsonoutput").innerHTML = json_result.results[0].series[0].values[0][5]
```

trhows the following error:

> e2e_check_new.php:172 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at e2e_check_new.php:172

Comment: We don't know. What _are_ you doing wrong…? What error or issue are you encountering?

Comment: Are you parsing the JSON in javascript? `var json_result = JSON.parse(inputstream);` Otherwise, it surely won't work, unless you are getting the json through an http request and you set content type application/json.

Comment: Where is your JavaScript that tries your decoding...? You likely need `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Show us how you get the PHP Json result into the browser and therefore javascript

Comment: Sorry for not providing more information. The Influxdb API returns a pretty formated JSON. Currently I output the whole JSON with: `var json_result = '<?php echo $javascript_json_result;?>'; document.getElementById("jsonoutput").innerHTML = JSON.parse(json_result);` which outputs the whole json. But I would like to output only single values. `document.getElementById("jsonoutput").innerHTML = json_result.results[0].series[0].values[0][5]` trhows the following error: e2e_check_new.php:172 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at e2e_check_new.php:172

Comment: Please EDIT that into your question. Nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: the error is because you need to run JSON.parse on the result before you can use it like an object - you're trying to use it like an object, but it's still a string. Alternatively you can inject it into the JS as an object literal by not using single quotes round your PHP: `var json_result = <?php echo $javascript_json_result;?>`, and then you can select a particular value in the way you've already shown in your comment.

Comment: Or var `json_result = <?php echo $javascript_json_result;?>;` and it will create `json_result` as a javascript object

Comment: Thanks! The single quotes were the issue. I removed them and now I parse the variable with JSON.parse(json_result) and it works.

Comment: If you already removed the single quotes then you already have a JS object. You shouldn't need to parse it again, it's already an object. Parse is for when you want to read a string and convert it to an object. Since you removed the quotes, you no longer have a string.

Comment: I thought the same, but it wasn't working without the JSON.parse.

Comment: @newduino not working how exactly? What was happening when you did it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong?
>
> ```
> var json_result = '<?php echo $javascript_json_result;?>';
> ```

You are trying to output the JSON as a string in JavaScript by wrapping it in `'` but you aren't escaping any of the characters in the JSON which have special meaning in JavaScript (like `\` or a new line or `'` - it looks like you definitely have at least new lines in your JSON).

---

Don't try to generate a string of JSON. Just output the JSON directly so it will be treated as a JavaScript object literal.

```
var my_object = <?php echo $javascript_json_result; ?>; 
document.getElementById("jsonoutput").innerHTML = my_object;
```

… of course, this will convert the object to the string `[Object object]` which isn't useful. You can deal with the data structure in the usual ways though (i.e. access properties etc).